# How to represent non-linear operators computationally?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, operator-theory, nonlinear-system

I have a finite dimensional vector space V, and want to compute a non-linear operator $R: V \rightarrow V$.

I want to have a "general" form of this operator R.  I think of the following series expansion:
$$ R = a_0 I + a_1 T + a_2 T^2 + a_3 T^3 + ... $$
where T is a linear operator over V.  But it seems that the above R would become a matrix and that is itself a linear operator.  Something wrong?

Secondly, if the above series is correct, and if I truncate the series to approximate the operator, I am not sure if the truncation has the "nice" property as in truncation of the series expansion of a real or complex single-variable function...

I just want a general form of a non-linear operator so my algorithm can approximate it.  My training data takes the form of some vectors in V and after the transformation they would become some other vectors.

Edit:  I assume people working in numerical methods, would have some ways to manipulate non-linear operators.  What kind of representations are available for them?  (Matrices are linear and their polynomials and power series are still linear.)

Comment: What if $V=\mathbb R$ and $R(z)=\sqrt z$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza What is $T$ in your example? (Here $R(z)$ is not a function $V \to V$ but that can be easily rectified.)

Comment: (Oops, I accidentally deleted my comment, which asserted that if the series for $R$ converges, then it defines a linear operator.)

Comment: Just edited my answer. I took it as linearity in matrix A.

Comment: Michael Galuza:  yes, that would be an example, but it cannot be expressed in matrix form, can it?  Or a parametric form that is dense in the space of non-linear operators.

Comment: You can write Taylor series for an operator, but that would look like
$$
R(\mathbf x+\mathbf h) = \mathbf R(\mathbf x) + A(\mathbf x) \mathbf h + 
B(\mathbf x) (\mathbf h \otimes \mathbf h) + C(\mathbf x) (\mathbf h \otimes \mathbf h \otimes \mathbf h) + \dots
$$ where $k$-th term is a tensor of $k$-th order, i.e. $k$-linear form.

Answer (score 2):

First part: Assuming the series on right does converge to R, then R will be linear operator. 
For ex.  For any matrix $A$,  $$exp(A) := \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{A^n} {n! } $$ is a linear operator as $exp(A)(k u + t v) =k ~exp(A)u +t~ exp(A)v $ for real number $k, t$. 
Regarding second part, series will have all the "nice" properties like series of real or complex numbers if it is known to be convergent (in your appropriate space).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  So any polynomial or power series constructed from A, if A is linear, would still result in a linear operator (or matrix), provided it converges.  That means I cannot obtain non-linear operators using such tricks...

Comment: No but it might be possible to get a good linear approximation for your non-linear operator.

Comment: Yes if you mean "local" approximation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested in the Functional Calculus ( of different types)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus  ?

Comment: Not sure... but how can I use that to represent a non-linear operator?  Something that will give me a family of non-linear operators?